# ImportError: cannot import name '_representation' in python3.5 (all modules upgraded)

Tags: python-3.5, importerror, statsmodels

I pip installed statsmodels, and when i tried to run the following codes:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

as well as

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.kalman_filter import (INVERT_UNIVARIATE, SOLVE_LU)
```

I have this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name '_representation'

I have searched similar from other posts, and upgraded my statsmodels, numpy, scipy, pandas, etc. and hence i have statsmodels 0.9.0, numpy 1.14.5, scipy 1.1.0 and pandaas 0.23.1 - but still running into the same issue.

Curious if any of you would have some suggestion?
Thanks very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved after i uninstalled all packaged (dependent on numpy) and re-installed everything.